# SPFx extension samples not showing

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I've tried several samples [SPFx extensions](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples). All samples have the same outcome when it comes to testing (`gulp serve`) after following the instructions on the samples page.

Most of them just require `npm install` and adjustments in the serve.json file. However, every time I'm testing it, the extension somehow is not loaded. I won't get an error or anything, but it just doesn't load/execute.

Even when I'm following the [helloworld tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint) on the official tutorial series, the extension won't show (except the alert from the very first step).

I also tried on different machines and in different networks, but I was never able to get the samples to do something.

Does anyone have an idea?

Node.js version: 10.15.3
npm version: 6.4.1
gulp version: 2.1.0

Edit: If you try it with NodeJS 8.16 LTS it still has the [same problem](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3705#issuecomment-486848620).

Comment: Have you tried with node js 8.x? Not sure if that will fix your issue but that is the currently supported version for SPFx.

Comment: Please try with NODE 8.x version and check whether if it is working.
MSDN link : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jalvv.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jalvv.jpg)

Comment: I installed SPFx 8.15, but unfortunately have the same outcome. My colleagues tried it as well with the same result